# How to generate bullet points in PowerPoint with office-js?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I've created an Office-Add in with a button that executes the following function

```
export function generateBulletPoints(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {
  const data = `* foo
   * bar`
  Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(data)
}
```

This inserts the text into the current selection. However, the text is not converted and formatted into bullet points in PowerPoint, like it would if I typed this text out manually. I've also attempted using unicode (• instead of *), but the formatting still isn't equal to manually adding bullet points in PowerPoint.

How can I add proper bullet points to text in PowerPoint using office-js?

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately no